# How can I change how my tag pages display?

Tags: loop, theme-twenty-ten

Ok, I'm using the TagCloudShortCode plugin. I have a problem with how my tag pages display.... I want them to display the way they show on my main page, with the image and more button... how do I change the way it displays?

I want it to display like this `http://www.top-iphone-apps.info/`

but it displays like this `http://www.top-iphone-apps.info/?tag=free`

(I know very little about coding, so try to be specific, and if you give me code explain what each line does so I can learn please)

thanks!

Update... 
I fixed it by changing this in the index.php file

```
<?php if ( is_archive() || is_search() ) : // Only display excerpts for archives and search. ?>
            <div class="entry-summary">
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
```

to

```
<?php if ( is_archive() || is_search() ) : // Only display excerpts for archives and search. ?>
            <div class="entry-content">
                <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyten' ) ); ?>
                <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyten' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

basically copying the stuff from the else statemnt. It worked, but I know it's a sloppy way of fixing it, so if anyone can tell me the better way of doing it I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the root of your issue is that WordPress has two very different template tags to output posts: [`the_content()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content) and [`the_excerpt()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt). There are a lot of nuances with these and many get details wrong, I did my best to get everything right in post at my blog if you are interested that [Make sense of WordPress excerpts and teasers](http://www.rarst.net/script/wordpress-excerpt-teaser/).

In this specific case you want `the_content()`, but theme uses `the_excerpt()`.

Simply editing it as in your follow-up in question is not really sloppy, actually it is the only (non-messy) way to change one of these to another.

Problem is you will lose your edits next time you update Twenty Ten (or WordPress, since Twenty Ten is part of package).

The slightly more complex, but solid and upgrade proof way is to create child theme for Twenty Ten and apply your tweaks there.

1. Create child theme, see [Child Themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) in Codex. It uses Twenty Ten as example, should be easy to follow.
2. Switch to your child theme, at start it would be identical to Twenty Ten.
3. Create file `loop-tag.php` in your child theme's folder.
4. Copy content of Twenty Ten `loop.php` to that `loop-tag.php` you created.
5. Apply your edits to `loop-tag.php` (you can probably just throw out extra stuff if you feel like it, this file will only load for tag archive pages).

Comment: I'll probably never update, but I'm saving your answer in case I ever do.  Thank you!

Comment: I want to stress that even you ignore Twenty Ten updates it **will** be forcefully updated next time you update WordPress. So child theme is very very good practice to follow for theme changes.

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much, but I can't think of a good reason to update wordpress either lol....  especially since I assume that would also change what I've added to the functions.php as well as potentially making some of my plugins not work, although for my organization and to make future edits easier child themes would still be a good idea.

Comment: It is **highly** recommended to always keep WordPress updated, especially for security reasons. As for `functions.php` same applies - you need to create child theme for it to be update-proof.

Answer (score 0):

open the file "tag.php" in an an editor, replace

```
get_template_part( 'loop', 'tag' );
```

with

```
get_template_part( 'loop', 'index' );
```

Comment: Surprisingly that didn't work...  I thought it would... wonder if there is something somewhere else... if only I knew how to do a hook function like I found for changing the "read more" look.  If it matters I'm using the default theme Twenty Ten

Comment: hey, my search results do the same thing! That's gotta go too!  could it have something to do with this bit in the index.php?  '<?php if ( is_archive() || is_search() ) : // Only display excerpts for archives and search. ?>
   <div class="entry-summary">
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
   </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
 <?php else : ?>
   <div class="entry-content">
    <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyten' ) ); ?> '

Comment: Twentyten doesn't provide alternative Loop templates, the second argument is just for convenience of child themes.

Comment: ahhhhh, I kinda get that, only because tag.php said something about creating another file if you wanted to overload something. although not quite sure what a child theme is